# Recommendations for a web application with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, typescript

Im creating a web application with PHP (Laravel 5.*) and currently AngularJS (1.*). There are some components of the website that i want to build with Angular. For example a Form Generator. A user can click buttons and define which kind of field he/she would like to create. After that, the user can implement it on his website and receive submissions on it. This can be a small app build with Angular.

Currently Angular 2 is a R.C. version, which can be released soon. To keep myself triggered with the newest techniques, i started to explore it a bit and noticed the TypeScript with compiler which runs behind the public(_html) of a application.

Lets split my application in URLs to make my question simpler:

```
www.domain.com/form-generator -> Uses the script: /angular/form-generator/mainModule.js

www.domain.com/easy-importer -> Uses the script: /angular/easy-importer/mainModule.js

www.domain.com/my-other-small-app-> Uses the script: /angular/my-other-small-app/mainModule.js
```

Is it possible, efficient and recommendable to create small modules/apps that are loaded on base of the application i build instead of loading them all together? Is Angular 2 recommendable for this or should i consider jQuery and keep Angular 1.*?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a front-end framework to use with Laravel, I reccomend [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/guide/). Taylor Otwell, the creator of Laravel, has indicated that vue.js is his [front-end framework of choice](http://blog.evanyou.me/2015/12/20/vuejs-2015-in-review/#Highlights).

Keep in mind, you can use any front-end framework you want. Research what's out there and pick based on your needs. Laravel is not tied to any single front-end: it's your decision.

I only suggest vue.js because it's been adopted by a significant portion of the Laravel community. That community can help you out when you get stuck, and have resources to help you get started. Personally, I watched [the Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step) by Jeffrey Way to get up to speed.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but i would like to hear arguments. Why Vue? Is it recommended for my application type? Is it fast?

Comment: "Is it fast" is not a well defined question. Vue.js has a [comparison](https://vuejs.org/guide/comparison.html) to other frameworks in their docs.